# Solution to algebraic equation displayed in terms of variable rather than inputted integer value of variable?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to code an interactive calculator in Python 3, but my code returns my solutions in terms of the variable rather than its inputted integer. This is my code thus far:

```
from sympy import *
t = int(input('input your number'))
i, t, x = symbols('i, t, x', int = True)
eq = (summation(10/((1+x)**t), (i, 0, t))) - 100000 
n = solve(eq, [x])
print(n)
```

This returns my solutions in t, so for example if I input t as 5:

```
[-1 + (3*t + 3) * * (1/t)/10 * * (2/t)]
```

How could I instead get it to show the solution as 0.2903331792 instead?

I've also tried setting the input as int(input(... as well as setting t = int

Edit: the summation function is being used to iterate the expression 10/((1+x)**t for as many times in t as inputted if that makes things clearer. Please say if this is wrong.

Edit 2: solved!, removed t from symbols(...

Comment: what happens if you don't define `t` as a symbol and thus overwriting the input value?

Comment: `i,t,x=...` line defines `t` as `Symbol`, replacing the initial number assignment.  `sympy` runs in Python, so basic Python syntax and evaluation applies.

Comment: In `eq` whiich use of `t` is supposed to be `5.0` as opposed to a free variable?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but would I still need (i, 0, t) within the equation line? 
Edit: I seem to have misinputed a line of code, doh!, amended. t should be t = int(input(...

Comment: How you set `t` initially doesn't matter, whether as (simpler 5.0) or via `input`.  What matters is what `t` is when used in `eq`.

Answer (score 0):

You might think of conceptually dealing with the variable and its value separately. So you define a symbolic equation, input a value for a symbol in that equation, and then *substitute* the symbol with the value before solving:

```py
from sympy import *
i, t, x = symbols('i, t, x', int = True)
eq = (summation(10/((1+x)**t), (i, 0, t))) - 100000 
tval = int(input('input your number'))
print(solve(eq.subs(t, tval), [x]))
```

Or, since you can already get a solution *symbolically* for `x` in terms of `t`, you can just substitute the value into that expression and not have to re-solve the equation each time:

```py
xsol = solve(eq, x, dict=True)[x]
while 1:
    tval = int(input('input your number'))
    print(xsol.subs(t, tval))
```